# Where should introductory material for Documentation tags/topics go?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I am quite confused on where to put introductory material for a given topic or tag.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/77664), I have created a page for **Trees** under the `algorithm` tag, with an **Introduction** example. However, I could very well put this overview of the topic under Remarks, as I have seen on other pages.

**Should I put the introductory section within Remarks or its own example? Or is there another solution?**

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what other examples you imagine putting in that topic.

- If it's a bunch of algorithms, then I'd say put the definition of tree in the Remarks, yeah.
- If you want to talk about trees but not algorithms, there's [the data structures tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data-structures/topics).